# Couple Brikka and Moka

Tags: induction

I have induction stove and want to use Brikka on it, but as far as I know:

- Brikka is always Alu
- there are versions of Moka from stainless steel

I want to couple them together:

- take bottom part from induction Moka
- take upper part from Brikka

Unfortunately I do not have any shops around me to check it. If anybody has several Bialettis - can you please check if they are compatible or not?